# PHP custom errorhandler not working

Tags: php, class, custom-error-handling

I found a piece of Code here on StackOverFlow for an error handler.
The problem that I am facing is exactly as where the topic starter asked about.

The errors simply do not get reported.
A little frustrating since I really need a decent error handler. *I found a beautiful one from Joseph Lenton but it absolutely breaks everything I want to make* So I need to create my own that works for me.

**The problem:**

It does not report any errors?? :S

```
    <?php
class class_error
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // set to the user defined error handler
        set_error_handler([$this, 'errorHandler']);
    }

    public function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        //don't display error if no error number
        if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
            return;
        }

    //display errors according to the error number
    switch ($errno)
    {
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            echo "<b>ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
            echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
            echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
            exit(1);
            break;

        case E_USER_WARNING:
            echo "<b>WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            echo "<b>NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        default:
            echo "<b>UNKNOWN ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;
    }

        //don't execute PHP internal error handler
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

I call the script :

```
<?php 
include('function.errorhandler.class.php');
$error = new class_error();

echo 'dssd;
?>
```

I still keep getting the same old PHP generated errors. :o

So let's get back to basic because it seems impossible again to make even the simplest things work.

```
<?php
include('function.errorhandler.class.php');

///######## DEFAULT ERROR HANDLER
set_error_handler('ErrorHandler');
///######## SHUTDOWN HANDLER
register_shutdown_function('FatalErrorHandler');
///######## A FILE BECAUSE PHP DOES NOT WANT TO ACCEPT ANY ERROR HANDLER IN THE SAME FILE
include('hi.php');
?>
```

And defined in the errorhandler.class file :

```
function ErrorHandler(){
    exit(print_r(func_get_args()));
}
function FatalErrorHandler(){
    exit(print_r(func_get_args()));
}
```

Still I get the same old rusty PHP error notice :

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''sdds; ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in N:\wamp\www\project\errorhandler\hoi.php on line 3
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0003  240376  {main}( )   ..\errorHandler.php:0
Array ( ) 1

Answer (score 0):

The script you use to test the error handler contains a syntax error. Therefore the script does not execute and your error handler is never used.

So the php file that includes the error handler should be syntactically correct. Any other include files, after the error handler is enable, will make use of your error handler.

Comment: I added the syntax error intentionally. To rigger the erorr. But if I move it to an included file it also keeps from working.

`<?php 
include('function.errorhandler.class.php');
$error = new class_error();


include('hi.php');
?>`

Comment: Well, that's another question then. Seemingly your error handler does not work at all. Simply ask a new question. You cannot ask new questions in a comment. Anyway, did you get what you did wrong? (Tip, make really sure your error class is included, place an echo in it for instance).